# How to simulate certain street number value in Chrome autofill?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, autofill, chakra-ui

I'm working on a React app which has a form for filling the contact data of a user. Autofill is enabled. There is a validation mechanism which is using an external service to check if a given address really exists.

From time to time Sentry catches a 400 error when the value of street number field is something unexpected. The field is limited to 10 alphanumeric characters. In the latest example, instead of only the number (e.g. "12"), the content of this field was the entire address (e.g. "Random Street 12", so something longer than 10 characters). We believe that's an issue with autofill, when a user has some malformed address saved in the browser.

One of my ideas was to somehow disable autofill, at least for this field. But I'm interested in other possible approaches, so I would appreciate your ideas.

However, I would first like to try to repoduce the issue locally, but I'm not sure how exactly to do it. For example, I tried to add a dummy address like this one in Chrome's *Settings -> Autofill -> Addresses and more*:
[image]

...but it didn't fill the "Street number" field with "111 some dummy text" when I started entering the data in the form. How can I do this?

We are using some wrapped components, but eventually the field is a Chakra's Input component with the `name` and `id` equal to "streetNo".

Edit: Now I'm reading the question and I'm realizing it's not clear enough what I really want to ask, so let me recap:

1. How can I create a dummy address stored in Chrome to test this
   autofill feature so it puts something like "123 ABC XYZ WHATEVER"
   into the street number field?
2. What is the best way to prevent loading wrong data into this ield (or at least to somehow limit it)?